# Get propetary rom info from adb shell

Tags: adb, rom, shell, xiaomi, miui

I have xiaomi smartphone which uses miui rom interface. I'm developing a windows program which manages the smartphone, I want to get the Miui version info which is displayed in settings->about phone, but there it is not in build.prop, so I can't use adb shell getprop. 
How can I access that exact string which is displayed under miui version by windows? Thank you

[image]

Comment: That's one of the things my little tool [Addebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) does. For details, take a closer look at [deviceinfo.lib](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar/blob/master/lib/deviceinfo.lib), especially the function `getDeviceInfo()`. for the line in question, check the output of `adb shell getprop` and `grep` for "MIUI".